# How to get data from JavaScript getelementbyid

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, html

How to get data from JavaScript getelementbyid insert into Html input text?
Here is my sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
var currentUser;
function init(){
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    document.getElementById('userLoginName').innerHTML = ''; 
    document.getElementById('userId').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('userTitle').innerHTML = currentUser.get_title();
    document.getElementById('userEmail').innerHTML = '';
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
<div>Current Logged User:
<!--     <span Name="userLoginName"></span>
    <span Name="userId"></span>
    <span Name="userTitle"></span>
    <span Name="userEmail"></span> -->

    <input type="text" name="userLoginName" id="userLoginName">
    <input type="text" name="userId" id="userId">
    <input type="text" name="userTitle" id="userTitle">
    <input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, i think you should use document.getElementById('#userTitle').innerHTML if userTitle is a text box with ID "userTitle"

Comment: In between this question should be asked in Javascript stack exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using textboxes, just change the display means from ***innerHTML*** to ***value*** in your success block -

```
function onQuerySucceeded() { 
    document.getElementById('userLoginName').value= currentUser.get_loginName(); 
    document.getElementById('userId').value= currentUser.get_title();; 
    document.getElementById('userTitle').value= currentUser.get_title(); 
    document.getElementById('userEmail').value= currentUser.get_email();
}
```

Comment: @junreyd pls mark the answer completed if it resolves ur issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You update/add value attribute of element like below

`document.getElementById('userTitle').setAttribute("value", currentUser.get_title())`;